# Как реализовать кнопку рестарта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я начал делать свой 1-ый проект на юнити и столкнулся с тем, что не работает кнопка рестарта.

Смотрел все возможные гайды на эту тему, но не один код не работает и выпущены эти туториалы 1 - 4 года назад.

Подскажите как правильно сделать кнопку рестарта.

Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геймплейно рестарт можно реализовать как угодно. На это не может быть однозначного ответа, всё зависит от вашей реализации самого понятия старта.

Но если это ваш первый проект то я подразумеваю что под рестартом имеется в виду повторная загрузка игровой сцены.

Для этого вам необходимо реализовать метод с загрузкой сцены в одном из ваших скриптов:

```
public void Restart()
{
   SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
   // Загружает самую первую (0) установленную в проекте сцену. 
   // Если необходимо загрузить не её укажите какую именно сцену нужно загрузить
}
```

Для реализации метода `LoadScene()` - необходимо будет подключить пространство имён:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Затем вложить скрипт или использовать объект на сцене где уже вложен данный скрипт с Рестартом на кнопку в `OnClick` и из списка выбрать сначало свой скрипт далее метод с Рестартом.

**(НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ САМ СКРИПТ, ВЛОЖИТЕ СКРИПТ В ОБЬЕКТ НА СЦЕНЕ ДАЛЕЕ ОБЪЕКТ СО СЦЕНЫ В `OnClick`)**

Пример:
[image: Пример]

Если всё сделали по пунктам то при нажатии сработает метод Restart(), и перезагрузится текущая сцена

Comment: `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` это пространство имён.

Comment: @こきん, спасибо! Подкорректировал